# Insert "variable from update" using Triggers in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table like this one:

```
create table person(
id_person number(5),
city varchar(20)
);

insert into person values (1, 'NY');
insert into person values (2, 'Los Angeles');
```

I want to register "person" movements into a new table:

```
create table move_city(
new_location varchar(200)
);
```

And I have a trigger to do this:

```
create or replace trigger person_movement
after update of city on person
for each row
begin
insert into move_city values('The person has moved from ' ||:old.city|| ' to ' || :new.city);
end;
/
```

And is working as expected.

If I do:

```
update person set city='Boston' where id_person=1;
```

I have on move_city:
'The person has moved from NY to Boston'

My problem is that I want to put the 'id_person' in 'move_city' and obtain something like 'The person with id .... has moved from NY to Boston', and I don't know what i have to do in my trigger.

I mean something like this on the trigger.

```
insert into move_city values('The person with ' ||id_person|| ' has moved from ' ||:old.city|| ' to ' || :new.city);
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Update:

I have tried with:

```
create or replace trigger person_movement
after update of city on person
for each row
declare
id2 person.id_person%type;
begin
select id_person into id2 from person where id_person=:new.id_person;
insert into move_city values('The person with ' ||id2|| ' has moved from ' ||:old.city|| ' to ' || :new.city);
end;
/
```

But when I do:

```
update person set city='Boston' where id_person=1;
```

I obtain:

ORA-04091: table SYSTEM.PERSON is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.PERSON_MOVEMENT", line 4

ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.PERSON_MOVEMENT'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `:new` or `:old` here:

```
INSERT INTO move_city
  ( new_location )
VALUES
  ( 'The person with ' || :new.id_person|| ' has moved from ' ||:old.city|| ' to ' || :new.city);
```

However, I think for your `move_city` table the best thing to do would be to have separate columns for `id_person`, `old_location`, and `new_location`, then add the supporting information when you retrieve the data from the table. That way you might do:

```
INSERT INTO move_city
  ( id_person, old_location, new_location )
VALUES
  ( :new.id_person, :old.city, :new.city );
```

(It would also be a good idea to have a `DATE` column in `move_city` with a default value of `SYSDATE`.)

And in your trigger you could only do the insert where `old.city` differs from `new.city`:

```
IF ( old.city != new.city OR old.city IS NULL ) THEN
    INSERT INTO move_city
      ( id_person, old_location, new_location )
    VALUES
      ( :new.id_person, :old.city, :new.city );
END IF;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I have to do it as I said

Comment: Well, the answer to your question is at the top. Good luck